# За останні пів року чи упродовж останнього пів року?

Tags: граматика, числівники, узгодження-слів

Як правильно узгоджується пів із рештою речення (з наступним іменником у родовому відмінку все зрозуміло). Пів означає половину, наприклад, пів року – це якийсь один відрізок часу, тож, на мою думку, тут було б логічніше застосувати однину – упродовж останнього пів року. Але частіше вживається множина – за останні пів року. Якими правилами це можна було б пояснити?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(лише своє слово)*

#### Як правильно узгоджується пів із рештою речення

Справа в тому, що ці пів не узгоджуються, а узгоджуєте ви. Так, адже ви є тією людиною, яка скаже чи правильно чи ні використано слово на основі словникових значень, адже ви хочете передати певну думку. Вам потрібно лише зрозуміти основи (які на жаль сьогодні дуже сильно розмиті).

#### тут було б логічніше застосувати однину

Мова йде про половину року, або ж як варіянт яблука. Тобто маємо однину. Але ... є одне але. Дуже часто пів року вважають за 6 місяців і тут вже в теорії (хоча на мою думку є неправильним) можуть використати множину, можливо помилково, але логіці важко перечити.

Тобто у вашому ж запитанні вже закладена відповідь. Слідуйте логіці. Правильно задане запитання - це вже частина відповіді.

#### Але частіше вживається множина

Зараз і обсервацію часто вживають, але це не говорить про те, що це правильно. Тупо відкинули слово спостереження і використали іноземне слово. Без усіляких на те причин. Бо це круто. Бо це модно. Бо це, нібито, сучасно. Та й про лайку не забудьте, яку часто вживають і одночасно кажуть, що це погано, ще й пальчиком помахають.

Думаю, що через подібні вкидання перестають розуміти свою мову.

#### упродовж останнього пів року ... за останні пів року

Для мене це різні значення через використання слів упродовж та за. Бо на часовому графіку:

- за - подія за певною межею;
- упродовж - подія в певних межах (у про довж - про довжину, лише в середині довжини про яку йде мова).

*(Тут зараз почнуть мені тикати словником і показувати приклади зі словника про використання за, але зразу скажу, що я з цим не згоден. Тобто якщо маєте якісь інші докази, то це буде добре.)*

#### Якими правилами це можна було б пояснити?

Пояснювати логіку можна лише логікою.

#### Трохи джерел для роздумів

[Звідси](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine16-10.pdf)

> Як свідчать спостереження, типовою формою прикметника, що виступає
>   означенням до іменника з пів-, є форма родового відмінка множини, яка
>   вказує на сприймання іменника з пів- як сполучення кількісного слова з
>   іншим іменником, наприклад: Він навмисне пройшов зайвих пів квартала,
>   щоб глянути на градусник (О. Донченко). Не вказує на рід  і форма
>   дієслова минулого часу у такому прикладі: Та як почнемо балакати та
>   пити, гляну, вже й пів дня минуло (І. Нечуй-Левицький) (пор.
>   тритижніминуло). Лише поодинокі приклади уживання прикметників та
>   іменників з пів- вказують на рід останніх:   ..сонце припікає, як
>   скажене, а йти ще цілого пів дня(П. Загребельний). Отже, значення роду
>   в аналізованій групі іменників ще не оформилось остаточно, бо
>   означення при них вживаються рідко.

Словник

> [ПІВ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2) - Те саме, що полови́на (у визначенні часу).
>
> Було ще рано, пів до восьмої. (М. Коцюбинський)
>
> Одержавши плату, Ліна о пів на шосту залишила бібліотеку. (С.
>   Добровольський)

#### Що не так із "останні (останнього) пів року"

Коли мова йде про час, то пів виступає у значенні половини. Тобто якщо є цілий рік, то пів року буде по середині року. Це саме той момент в середині року і не може бути цей момент останнім, бо він один.

Тобто сам вираз не логічний.

#### Висновок

А отже пропозиція від @Sasha правильна щодо зміни вашого виразу на:

- упродовж останнього [півріччя](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%D1%87%D1%8F) - відрізок часу тотожний половині року до цього моменту;
- за останнє півріччя - відрізок часу, що знаходиться поза останнім півріччям в одному з двох напрямків: майбутнього або минулого.

#### Ламаємо простір-час )

Щоб добити також хочу звернути увагу, що можна сказати і так: о пів останнього року. Іншими словами: мітка на відрізку часу, яку знайдете на середині останнього року.

---

*Кожен сам собі обирає набір слів, але для розуміння потрібно домовити загальні основи.*

Comment: "... але це не говорить про те, що це правильно", – повністю погоджуюся, тому й намагаюся з'ясувати, що стоїть за поширеними варіантами слововживання та чи немає кращого й більш правильного способу формулювання думки. Дякую за ґрунтовну відповідь

Comment: 3 «пів року» вживають множину не тому, що сприймають як 6 місяців, а тому, що «пів» (як окремий числівник, звісно, а не як частина слова а-ля «півострів») граматично вважається множиною. Про «пів яблука» Ви теж кажете «мої пів яблука», а не «моє пів яблука».

Comment: @Sasha Можете навести джерело, де кажуть прямо, що пів, це числівник у множині?

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, ні. Лише статистику траплянь. Ну й здоровий глузд — невже Ви серйозно пропонуєте казати «моє пів яблука»? («Моє напів'яблуко» — так. «Моє пів'яблуко» — можливо, якщо вважати, що такое слово існує. Але «мої пів яблука», а не «моє пів яблука».)

Comment: @Sasha Якщо неможливо довести, що пів - це множина, або хоч щось, що вказує на множину і навіть навпаки все вказує на однину, то для чого використовувати множину?

Comment: @Sasha Якщо немає доказів про множину слова пів, тоді так. Я не бачу логічних причин використовувати множину в даному випадку.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, я бачу, Ви й самі знайшли джерело, що стверджує про типовість множини й поодинокість однини. (Єдине що: воно також стверджує типовість родового відмінку. Але насправді і називний, і родовий відмінки є типовими — [про це каже Антоненко-Давидович](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/chyslivnyky#uzhodzhennya-prykmetnykiv-z-imennykamy-pry-chyslivnykah), причому сам Антоненко-Давидович надає перевагу називному, і на практиці називний теж трапляється більш ніж удвічі частіше.)

Comment: «За останні пів року» і «за останнє півріччя» — не зовсім те саме. _Півріччя_ в певному контесті може позначати проміжки часу з фіксованими початком і кінцем, а не будь-які довжиною _пів року_ (наприклад, у школі 1-ше навчальне півріччя з вересня до грудня; у податковій 1-ше півріччя — це січень-червень). Наприклад, якщо я сьогодні (7.04.2020) кажу «останні пів року мені не щастило», то я, імовірно, маю на увазі приблизно 7.10.2019–7.04.2020, а якщо я кажу «останнє півріччя мені не щастило», то я, як підприємець, цілком можу мати на увазі ще не завершене податкове півріччя січень-червень.

Comment: @Sasha Я відстоюю думку, що за, у значенні обмеженого відрізку часу від-до логічно неможлива область. Бо область за. Слово за обмежує час лише початковою точкою. В даному випадку це або пів року, де неможливо використати слово останній, або півріччя і тоді треба уточнити в який бік від останнього півріччя лежить область значень часу. Якщо мова лише про область значень всередині останнього півріччя, то треба використати упродовж.

Comment: @Yola, не думаю, що варто виправляти такі речі. По-перше, те, що конструкції, які Андрій Іванченко вжив, чимось погані, — не факт (вони цілком зафіксовані в словниках і вживаються на практиці; так, можливо, вони мають польське походження, але чи обов'язково це погано? так можна прийти до війн правок, коли один виправляє «ні один/ніякий» на «жоден», а інший — «жоден» на «ні один/ніякий»). По-друге, тут деякі учасники цілком свідомо відходять від чинних норм і пишуть в своєму стилі — непевен, що це добре, але я вже зарікся виправляти те, що не є очевидною помилкою, раптом це частина стилю…

Comment: @Yola, але висловити Андрію свої погляди на ці конструкції й запропонувати приєднатися до них / виправити було б непоганою ідеєю.

Comment: @Yola, хоча, може, я й неправий щодо «не виправляйте» (адже він може відкотити). Але це все-таки не edit suggestion, а саме edit. Шкода, що SE не дозволяє (коли репутація сягає якогось числа) робити саме edit suggestions до автора/спільноти.

Answer (score 2):

Незалежно від того, який сполучник Ви вживатимете (*за* чи *впродовж*), *пів* зазвичай узгоджується з прикметником у множині. Тобто *«за останні(х) пів року»* або *«упродовж останніх пів року»*, але не *«за останнє пів року»* чи *«упродовж останнього пів року»*. Бо *«останні(х) пів року»*, а *не «останнє пів року»*.

У корпусі «ГРАК»:

- у множині — [784 трапляння](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/sortx?q=aword,[tag=".*adj:p.*"]+(([word="%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2"]+[word="%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83"])+|+[word="%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83"])&corpname=grac7&sattr=doc.date);
- в однині — [65 траплянь](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/sortx?q=aword,[tag=".*adj:n.*"+%26+word=".*%D0%B3%D0%BE(%D1%81[%D1%8C%D1%8F])?"+%26+!+word=".*(%D1%88%D0%B5?|[%D0%92%D0%A3%D0%B2%D1%83]%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)"]+(([word="%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2"]+[word="%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83"])+|+[word="%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83"])&corpname=grac7&sattr=doc.date) — і зауважте, що в частині з цих траплянь, можливо, мається на увазі *«піврік»* (тобто те, що нормативно зараз називається *півріччя*), а не, власне, *пів року*.

<sub>Доповнення. Ви можете спробувати сказати *«упродовж останнього „півроку“ (півріччя)»*, маючи на увазі *«піврік»* (*півріччя*), а не, власне, *пів року*. Тоді це окремий випадок — іменник *«піврік»* (*півріччя*), який слід писати разом, а не *пів чогось*. Але зазначу, що сучасні словники не містять такого слова — *«піврік»* (лише *півріччя*, або ж *пів року*).</sub>

Comment: Можете навести джерело, де сказано прямо, що пів - це множина? Статистичні дані не є показником правильності використання. Вони лише кажуть як використовують в певних джерелах. А звички бувають і поганими.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, ні. Лише статистику траплянь.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, реальні вжитки — це саме те, на основі чого в ідеалі мають формуватися словники й мовознавчі поради. (Єдине, що мене турбує, — це те, що траплянь в однині теж порівняно багато, тобто не виключено, що й однину _теж_ можна. Але множину можна — це 100%.)